# usr/bin/env: 'bash': no such file directory

Tags: ruby, bash, terminal, installation

I just downloaded Ubuntu yesterday. needless to say, I'm very new to everything including the terminal. I wanted to download ruby using this code I found here in https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04.

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby- build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

rbenv install 2.3.1
rbenv global 2.3.1
ruby -v
```

but I keep getting this error after opening a new terminal.

```
/usr/bin/env: 'bash': No such file or directory
```

thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: The error indicates your code cannot find the `bash` shell when executed, probably at the `exec $SHELL` line.  What does `echo $SHELL` give you from the command line?  What does `echo $SHELL` give you from within the script (please add it and run your code)?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I feel like you are speaking in mandarin right now. can you please tell me what to do so I can download ruby and learn programming.

Comment: Digressing a little from your question, I want to ask that would your problem be solved if I suggest a better way to install ruby?

Comment: I apologize.  Let's backup - I just want to see what the contents of the $SHELL variable looks like when you open a terminal session.  Open a terminal session and enter `echo $SHELL` and see what you get.

Comment: definitely. right now, my goal is to learn ruby on rails and I've subscribed in Lynda.com.

Comment: I get /bin/bash sir.

Comment: Woah then you have done the bestEST thing: Go through Kevin Skoglund essential training on Ruby on Rails. Its really fully worth.

Comment: Ok. Thx.  If you just want to install Ruby on Rails then I would go with user @Harsh Trivedi suggestion and not waste time troubleshooting the code you mentioned above.  Let us know if it all works out well.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when trying to open a subprocess from a python script.
I could identify that in some point of my script, the PATH environment variable was been overloaded.

The problem was fixed by removing the part of code that made this variable overloading.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot stress this enough, but trust me this is the best way ( according to my 3-4 years of experience) to install ruby (and ruby on rails if you like) on Ubuntu: Follow this blog: [here](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/)

Sorry if I have digressed from your question, but I believe your purpose is installing ruby only.

Best of luck with Ruby.

Comment: I'm on his course right no but installing Ruby on Linux isn't in his course. I really can't continue without installing ruby.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you keep this problem aside and restart with the instructions on linked Ryan Bigg blog. Make sure you follow each and every step. You can comment if you have problem with that.

Comment: well then, something's got messed up by things you did above. This might be more to ask, but can you clean the `~/.bashrc` file with extra things you exported with. These extra lines would be at the end of the file.

Comment: open it in any text editor of choice. For eg. `gedit ~/.bashrc` and check for the lines `export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH` and everything following. They should be last 2-3 lines (assuming the above code snippet is only what you have used). Remove them, and save the file. Once this is done run `source ~/.bashrc` and then tell what is output. If output is nothing, (no error) then i guess your problem is solved. Then be happy, and follow the Ryan Bigg blog without any more messing around. best of luck.

Comment: fixed it! http://askubuntu.com/questions/404424/how-do-i-restore-bashrc-to-its-default

Comment: Cool .. Now just blindly follow Ryan Bigg whenever you want to instal ruby. There are too many messy ways out there!  Hope you find this answer useful. Best of Luck.